# Map query string to controller method parameter in Kohana 3.2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana, kohana-3

I want to setup my route so that url like `word/startswith?prefix=ab` maps to following code

```
class Controller_Word extends Controller_Mytemplate {
    public function action_startswith($fragment){
     /// Here $fragment should get "ab" value.
    }
}
```

Also could anyone tell me how can I get GET data in Kohana 3.2 controller? For the above scenario I can solve it by,

```
class Controller_Word extends Controller_Mytemplate {
    public function action_startswith($fragment=null){
        if($fragment==null){
            /// set $fragment to $_GET['prefix'] but in Kohana way.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No answer! or even a comment! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use $this->request->query('prefix') ?

http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Request#query

Comment: +1 Completely new in KO3.2. Besides I didn't know `Request` object was assigned in `$this`. Do you know the route solution? Because I have much more actions

Comment: What route solution? As of 3.2 action_* methods in controllers should not have any parameters. Use $this->request->param('parameter name') instead. But in your case you want a query string, which is not part of the uri. So Request::query() is the way to go.